# JAVA(Android) - When comparing two strings even when they are the same It returns false

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have been having some issues when comparing the strings of 2 EditText boxes.
Here is the JAVA:

```
public void signUpSubmit(View v){
    ErrorBox.setText("");
    String eAdd = EmailAddress.getText().toString();
    String eAddConf = ConfirmEmail.getText().toString();
    String pass = Password.getText().toString();
    String passConf = ConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
    String fName = FirstName.getText().toString();
    String lName = LastName.getText().toString();

    Boolean emailSame;
    Boolean passSame;
    Boolean emailEmpty;
    Boolean passEmpty;
    Boolean fNameEmpty;
    Boolean lNameEmpty;

    if(eAdd.equals(eAddConf)){
        emailSame = true;
    }else{
        emailSame = false;
    }
    if(pass.equals(passConf)){
        passSame = true;
    }else{
        passSame = false;
    }
    if(eAdd.equals("")){
        emailEmpty = true;
    }else{
        emailEmpty = false;
    }
    if(pass.equals("")){
        passEmpty = true;
    }else{
        passEmpty = false;
    }
    if(fName.equals("")){
        fNameEmpty = true;
    }else{
        fNameEmpty = false;
    }
    if(lName.equals("")){
        lNameEmpty = true;
    }else{
        lNameEmpty = false;
    }

    Boolean noErrors;
    String ErrorCode = null;
    if(emailEmpty==true){
        noErrors=false;
        ErrorCode = "Email is Empty";
    }else if(fNameEmpty==true){
        noErrors=false;
        ErrorCode = "First name is Empty";
    }else if(lNameEmpty==true){
        noErrors=false;
        ErrorCode = "Last Name is Empty";
    }else if(passEmpty==true){
        noErrors=false;
        ErrorCode = "Password is Empty";
    }else if(emailSame==true){
        noErrors=false;
        ErrorCode = "Emails Don't Match";
    }else if(passSame==true){
        noErrors=false;
        ErrorCode = "Passwords Don't Match";
    }else{
        noErrors=true;
    }
    if (noErrors==false){
        ErrorBox.setText(ErrorCode);
    }else{
        String signUpStatus = signUpHttp(eAdd, pass, fName, lName);
        if (signUpStatus.equals("Error")){
            ErrorBox.setText("Server Down, Please Try Again Later");
        }else if (signUpStatus.equals("False")){
            ErrorBox.setText("That Email has already been used");
        }else if (signUpStatus.equals("True")){
            MainActUN.setText(eAdd);
            MainActPW.setText(pass);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I did have the repetitive if statements in their own function, but I did this to see if it would fix my problem but it didn't, any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT----------------------------------

Sorry about not being specific, if all the text boxes are filled, I get that the emails don't match, I have removed the email test and the same things happen saying the passwords don't match, however That the rest with .equals("") are fine.

Comment: This redundant code is redundant and is hard to read because of its redundancy.  What, specifically isn't working?  Are they all not working?

Comment: Indeed redundant, why not be specific of which two edit texts and the spot in the code that is behaving unexpectedly.

Comment: Please remove all this if...else! Just use e.g. "emailSame = eAdd.equals(eAddConf);" This will make the code much much easier to read and understand!

Comment: Some comments on the redundancy.  First off, `passSame == true` is the same as just `passSame` (and `passSame==false` is the same as `!passSame`.  Moreover, you're setting all these bools with a simple `if else` that only sets a bool variable.  Better would be simple `passSame == pass.equals(passConf);`, but BEST?  Best would be to simply not have `passSame` at all and just use `pass.equals(passConf);` or `!pass.equals(passConf)`.

Comment: @isnot2bad He doesn't even need `emailSame`.  He can just put `eAdd.equals(eAddConf);` every place he thinks he needs to check `emailSame`.

Comment: If nothing else, please make your code more succinct - e.g. `passEmpty = pass.equals("");`

Comment: Can you please check print that two edittext value before compare and then analyse.

Comment: @Homosapiens Please don't encourage use of print to debug for beginners. It has it's place but most of the time, like here, the debugger is the correct tool.  It would find this problem in 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if my pasta code reading skills are accurate.  Look at what you're doing here:

```
if(pass.equals(passConf)){
        passSame = true;
}else{
        passSame = false;
}
```

In plain English: "If the password and password confirmation match, passSame is true"

Now down here:

```
}else if(passSame==true){
    noErrors=false;
    ErrorCode = "Passwords Don't Match";
```

Don't you mean to set `noErrors` to true?

Even though the password and password confirmation passed your test (they are indeed the same), you make the passing condition into a failing test.  You're doing the same thing for your e-mail and e-mail confirmation.

String testing works, but your code marks a passing test as a fail. There's nothing wrong with the String comparison, but there's something wrong with your logic.

Just for the future, there's a great (ultimately pointless) debate among programmers about whether the opening curly brace should be on its own line or on the end of the preceding line. There is no debate, however, about where the closing curly brace goes.

```
}else{
```

is just fugly code. I have to agree that you need to strip out all of this redundant stuff. I know you did it for testing, but you're subjecting our eyes to some seriously stylistically atrocious code, which is not a nice thing to do given that you're asking us to look at it **for free**. Use a little more whitespace -- your code will be infinitely easier to read.

Write compact code (or as compact as Java will allow). Matching, testing, etc. can all be done in a couple of lines of code each. Java is a wordy enough language as it is.

Comment: Wow I didn't see that, I look like a right idiot lol. I will keep these points in mind if I need to post anything here in the future, thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. We've all made (and continue to make) plenty of mistakes. If you ain't dyin', you ain't tryin'. I hope you continue to post at SO. As you gain more experience, you'll be posting answers as well as questions, and you will help the community grow stronger.